# how to use getServerSideProps for a chain of multiple fetch() promises?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cors, fetch-api

I keep coming across a CORS issue specifically in regards to the second fetch (fetchURL2), where the fetch at fetchURL2 has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Below is my code for a chain of multiple fetch() promises where the second fetch is mapped to the data of the first fetch, but how do I use next.js getServerSideProps function to prevent the fetchURL2 from being blocked by the CORS policy above?

```
  fetch(fetchURL1, {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow',
    })
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        const responses = data.map((data) =>
            fetch(`${fetchURL2}/${data.slug}`)
                .then((res) => res.json()),
        );
        Promise.all(responses)
           .then(fetchedOrders => {
             console.log(fetchedOrders)
           })
```

Comment: Can you show us the CORS error you're getting? Requests made from inside `getServerSideProps` occur on the server-side (not the browser) and as such are not restricted by CORS.

Answer (score -2):

You need to allow the CORS for that specific endpoint to be able to work on your website.
Here's the line that must appear on your `Response Headers` :

[image]